# Without any prior run, on unpause airflow “catchup" the most recent completed valid period , with catchup = false . Can it be avoided?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Airflow version used : 1.10.4
As per documentation , we have kept start_date to a static date in past : 'datetime.strptime("12/31/1970", "%m/%d/%Y")'.
We use cron preset for schedule interval .
Tried setting cron value to a day before to ensure that there is only one dagrun created (schedule date + schedule interval) , but airflow schedules last schedule immediately after unpause and then creates one on next schedule interval time.

Is there a way to not run last prior schedule at all , with catchup = False ?
Constraint for us is that we cannot upgrade airflow version.

Referred to some of the workarounds in jira, but nothing worked as of now -

/jira/browse/AIRFLOW - 1056 .
/jira/browse/AIRFLOW - 3369

Looks like fix commit is made in version 1.10.11 and the issues was caused due to this piece of code in airflow's scheduler.py -

```
next_start = dag.following_schedule(now) 
last_start = dag.previous_schedule(now) 

if next_start <= now:
    new_start = last_start
else:
    new_start = dag.previous_schedule(last_start)

if dag.start_date:
    if new_start >= dag.start_date:
        dag.start_date = new_start
else :
        dag.start_date = new_start
```

help will be much appreciated !